# CMDer / ConEmu - Explorer current directory location

Tags: windows, cmd, console, conemu, cmder

I have `right click` integration with CMDer to pop up a console, but it's defaulting to my user directory instead of the directory I performed the `right click` in. If you press `Win+R` and run `cmd`, or hold `shift` and `right click` to open a command prompt from the context menu; the command prompt opens up at that location. I've been able to get CMDer/ConEmu to pick up on that use it, however it seems to be a plain command prompt, no additional features supported.

Ideally I could elevate to run as admin, have tried `-new_console:a` in the integration settings menu with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK CMDer forced your active directory to the user profile. Bare ConEmu do not do that. That's because cmder initialization scripts.

However without precise description hire do you set up your menu item (screenshot) and example of the directory you are trying it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what CMDer is doing, I noticed Clink is in the ConEmu settings and made a copy of Clink to there to use it. I used the integration settings and now have a `ConEmu Here` option in my right click explorer context. I was able to import the settings from my config xml CMDer was using, but for some reason the colours aren't working. Everything else seems to work fine now though. What part of settings do you want to see screenshot of? Or I could upload the config.xml?

Comment: Prompt coloring is done by `PROMPT` environment variable. And we do not need any screenshot if all is working.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding information on the `PROMPT` environment variable with ConEmu, what do I have to do to get this working with `ConEmu Here` so that colours will work properly?

Comment: Run `prompt /?` in the cmd.exe prompt. The `PROMPT` variable takes absolutely the same macros. You may find more information in the [ConEmu docs](http://conemu.github.io/en/CmdPrompt.html).

Answer (score 16):

You can go to Settings > Integration and set this in command field (upper section).

```
{bash} -cur_console:n:d:"%V"
```

`%V` is used to pass the current directory you are in.

After that you just need to hit the **Register** button in the upper section.
[image]

Comment: I found this answer the most useful thanks @tottomotto.

Comment: I also found https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html which I thought useful in explaining some of the switches that could be used

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem modifying the command syntax in registry. For example, it would look like that for the directories:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Cmder]
@="Cmder Here"
"Icon"="C:\\tools\\cmder\\icons\\cmder.ico"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Cmder\command]
@="\"C:\\tools\\cmder\\Cmder.exe\" \"%V\""
```

You can fix this for drives as well. Don't forget about `Background` section so you can use the menu option from blank space in Explorer.

To run the shell in elevated mode you may add "*" (asterisk) before the command in tasks setup, like this:
[image]

Here is the full .reg file employing the fix. Just replace the path with your cmder installation and enjoy.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\Background\shell\Cmder]
@="Cmder Here"
"Icon"="C:\\tools\\cmder\\icons\\cmder.ico"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\Background\shell\Cmder\command]
@="\"C:\\tools\\cmder\\Cmder.exe\" \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Cmder]
@="Cmder Here"
"Icon"="C:\\tools\\cmder\\icons\\cmder.ico"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Cmder\command]
@="\"C:\\tools\\cmder\\Cmder.exe\" \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Cmder]
@="Cmder Here"
"Icon"="C:\\tools\\cmder\\icons\\cmder.ico"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Cmder\command]
@="\"C:\\tools\\cmder\\Cmder.exe\" \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Cmder]
@="Cmder Here"
"Icon"="C:\\tools\\cmder\\icons\\cmder.ico"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Cmder\command]
@="\"C:\\tools\\cmder\\Cmder.exe\" \"%V\""
```

P.S. It just struck me that `%CMDER_ROOT` env var may be used instead of the absolute path.

Comment: I haven't worked with the registry in some time. The first snippet is what I probably have in registry for CMDer? And the last snippet you suggest copy/paste into a file with .reg extension, then run it so windows updates registry? `C:\\tools\\cmder\\` should be replaced with `%CMDER_ROOT`? Could you provide an example of what that might look like? I'm not sure if I need to adjust slashes/quotes/spaces.

Comment: "You can fix this for drives as well. Don't forget about `Background` section so you can use the menu option from blank space in Explorer." - Could you elaborate on this? I looked in ConEmu settings under Main>Background and couldn't see anything that made sense with what you were saying.

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked by passing in the command arguments: /START "%folder%"

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of cmder registering the right-click is enough.

Open the command prompt where cmder.exe exists. Then enter:

```
.\cmder.exe /REGISTER USER
```

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version just go to **Settings -> Integration  -> Register -> Save Settings**.

Note click the first register button of the upper section and then save the setting and its done, go to folder where you want to open the application press and hold **shift key and right click** and will appear **ComEmu Here** in dialog box.

It's for the latest versions.